# Two line chart from JSON on c3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

i've got a JSON that store multiple value like this,

```
[
  {"Description":"bankname1", "Month":"April", "Amount":"1700"},
  {"Description":"bankname1", "Month":"June", "Amount":"1300"},
  {"Description":"bankname1", "Month":"March", "Amount":"1500"},
  {"Description":"bankname2", "Month":"March", "Amount":"100"},
  {"Description":"bankname2", "Month":"April", "Amount":"1200"},
]
```

Into this JSON I've 12 Month for each Bankname (JSON can have multiple bank name). 
I would like to show a line-bar for each bankname and on x axis show Month name.

At this moment I can see only one line chart with value of bank mixed on name line.
this is my code:

```
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#c3_incassi',
        data: {
            json: data,
            keys: {
                x: 'MONTH', 
                value: ['AMOUNT']
            },
            type: 'line'
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                categories: ['GENNAIO', 'FEBBRAIO', 'MARZO', 'APRILE', 'MAGGIO', 'GIUGNO', 'LUGLIO', 'AGOSTO', 'SETTEMBRE', 'OTTOBRE', 'NOVEMBRE', 'DICEMBRE'],
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I solve this problem?
Many thanks
Bye

Francesco

Comment: what do you mean by line-bar chart?

Comment: [link](https://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html) Like this, on X axis I would like to show month name, on Y axis Amont, and instead of data1, data2 I would like to show Bankname

Comment: you can transform your json `data` to form `data: {
        columns: [
            ['bank1', 1, 2, 0, 3],
            ['bank2', 4, 5, 6, 7]
        ]
    }`  and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your json data into the correct format, as already commented by Abhas. The correct json format for c3.js line chart with multiple lines looks as follows:

```
{"bankname1":[1700,1300,1500,1100,1400,1800,2000,2100,1900,1100,1250,1050],"bankname2":[100,1200,300,1100,400,700,350,200,1200,1400,1050,900]}
```

The json string would contain the "bankname1" followed by 12 numeric values, one for each month, then "bankname2" followed by the 12 numeric values etc.

If you are using php at server-side, you can echo your json data, let's call it "dataset", into c3.js by:

```
var dataset = <?php echo $dataset; ?>;
data: { 
    json: dataset
},
```

I am doing it the excact same way and it works. The axis labels you can set up as in your code:

```
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: ['GENNAIO', 'FEBBRAIO', 'MARZO', 'APRILE', 'MAGGIO', 'GIUGNO', 'LUGLIO', 'AGOSTO', 'SETTEMBRE', 'OTTOBRE', 'NOVEMBRE', 'DICEMBRE'],
    }
}
```